# Unbeleviable code for tree of length any but not working

Tags: c++

i am trying to implementing tree of any length of string. this code is working for length of string 1 ,2, 3, 4 but Not working for above 5.
i have a main file but it shows error below. the problem is what i am trying to say is why this code work for upto length 4 string but when i enter length 5 string or above it really throw an error which is as under 
**OUTPUT**

1. Insert
2. Exit

Enter Your Choice: 1

Enter The String: asdfg
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 1s)

---

```
struct node
{
    string info;
    struct node *next[];
 }*front,*rear;
    void enqueue(string s)
        {
            node *p,*temp;
            p=new node[sizeof(node)];
            p->next[n.length()];
            p->info=s; 
            cout<<" pe "<<p->info;
            for (int i=0;i<n.length();i++)
            {
                p->next[i] = new node;
                p->next[i]=NULL;
            }
            if(front==NULL)
            {
                front=p;
                rear=p;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"cl"<<cl<<endl; 
                if(cl<n.length())
                    {
                    rear->next[cl]=p;
                    temp=rear->next[cl];
                    cout<<"chile-info "<<temp->info<<endl;
                    }   
            }      
        }
    void display()
{
    int k=0;
    node *t, *temp;
    t=front;

    if(front==NULL||rear==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nQueue Empty!!!";
    }
    else
    {
        temp=t;
       while(t!= NULL)
       {

           if(t->next[k] !=NULL)
           {
           temp=t->next[k]; 

           cout<<temp->info<<" ";
           }

           k++;
         if(k==n.length())
         {           
          k=0;
          t= t->next[k];
          temp=t;

         }

       }       
    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int ch,len,x;
string string1;
    rear=NULL;
    front=NULL;
        cout<<"\n1. Insert\n2. Exit\n";
        cout<<"\nEnter Your Choice: ";
        cin>>ch;

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                    cout<<"\nEnter The String: ";
                    cin>>n;
                    len=n.length();
                    enqueue(n);
                    cout<<" len "<<len;
                    for(int p=1;p<=len;p++)
                    bnod+=pow(len,p);

                    cl=0;
                    for (x=0;x<len;x++)
                      {
                         string1=n.at(x);
                         enqueue(string1);
                         cl++;
                      }
                     display();


         cout<<"\n########################\n";
                    break;
            case 2:
                    exit(0);
                    break;
            default:
                    cout<<"\nWrong Choice!!! Try Again.";
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you get crashes, either due to exception being thrown or other runtime errors, your first reaction as a programmer should be to run your program in a debugger. It will then stop when the crash/exception happens, and let you examine (and walk) the function call stack, as well as let you examine values of variables.

Comment: Why is this code unbelievable?

Comment: as i said work for upto 4th length not above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wrote this

```
        p=new node[sizeof(node)];
        p->next[n.length()];
```

what you actually wanted is this

```
        p = new node;
        p->next = new node*[n.length()];
```

This make no sense

```
            p->next[i] = new node;
            p->next[i]=NULL;
```

You allocate a node object then assign it to `p->next[i]`, and then the very next line you assign `p->next[i]` to NULL. Hard to say what you intend here, maybe this?

```
            p->next[i] = new node;
            p->next[i]->next = NULL;
```

Writing dynamic allocation code with pointers is hard. You need to think carefully about what the code you write really does.

Comment: p->next = new node*[n.length()]; error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘node**’ to ‘node* [0]’

Comment: So post the declaration of `node`. I'm doing my best to guess what you mean.

Comment: struct node
{
    string info;
    struct node *next[];
 }*front,*rear;

Comment: That isn't legal C++. Change it to `struct node { string info; struct node **next; }*front,*rear;` Now it should compile.

Comment: woooooooo you just rockkkkkkk

Comment: wait i got problem in display(); check post again with display

Comment: please check display()